# Expresso Store Shipping Error when Changing Shipping Method Before Shipping Details Entered

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

I have a store which ships to both the UK and to Australia (from the UK).

The default shipping plugin includes 4 methods – three are to the UK (Royal Mail First Class Standard, Next Day, Royal Mail Second Class Economy), and one for Royal Airmail to Australia. The three to the UK work fine, but the one to Australia returns this message on the checkout page when I change the shipping method in the dropdown box: Error calculating shipping: No rules match the current cart.

If I ignore that error message and continue to add my address in checkout two then continue on to checkout 3, the shipping is THEN calculated correctly, and I can continue on to payment.

How can I have the shipping calculated on checkout1 instead of returning the error (I don't mind that the user has to click update totals)? The buyer will not put in their address until checkout 2.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the best method is to let the customer put in their address before you show them the shipping options. You can't very well calculate the shipping costs without their address anyway.

Alternatively, you could change the rules for your Australia shipping method so that the cost applies worldwide. This means that if someone selects it before they enter their shipping address, they will still see the correct price, instead of an error message.

Comment: OK, perhaps I should put the shipping options on the final checkout page instead of the first. Thanks.